# c# EntityFramework Eager loading and group by issue

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, eager-loading

I am trying to get a nested List of Lists of rows grouped by a specific column.
My approach is like this:

```
public List<List<row>> 
MetaListRowsBySupplier(string orderNo)
    {
        return Entities.rows
                .Where(row => row.head.OrderNo == orderNo)
                .GroupBy(row => row.Item.Vendor)
                .Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();
    }
```

This works, but what I actually need inside the above is:

```
 return Entities.rows.Include("Item.Settings").Include("Details")
```

and this does not work because GroupBy makes the Include fail silently from what I can understand. 
Is there another way of having both GroupBy and Include pull through so
I get my list of lists of rows that has stuff already loaded that I need later on ?

I understand i could load the necessary things later by making new queries, but that seems cumbersome and prevents one-liners on separate lists later on, without opening a new database context, like for example:

```
foreach (row r in rows.Where(r => r.Item.Settings.First().FileType != "PDF"))
```

(For reference I need this because later I split the meta-list and do stuff with each list in separate Tasks.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is absolutely no benefit of performing such query in database. Apply your includes and insert `.AsEnumerable()` before `GroupBy`.

Comment: True, twice, but it's sad that EF(6) made it so counter-intuitive to understand when `Include` is effective. Logically there's no way to explain why EF should ignore the Includes here, but yeah, it does (because the shape of the query changes after the Include... what kind of reason is *that*?). That's one improvement in ef-core.

Comment: Thanks both, I will add '.AsEnumerable()' . I think it is a bit confusing that you can use Include, but it does not do anything and does not let you know. I tested and apparently you can also Include a non-existing or misspelled path and it won't throw an exception, but it will when you don't use '.GroupBy'.